# id of $.find control is undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to generate a control dynamicaly and after change another control. For example i have a button and a label, i want to change label's text using AJAX/JS/etc, without post/get queries. So i'm writing a code like this:

```
        foreach (var pair in FailedMonitorings)
        {
            var server = (ServerEnum)pair.Key;
            var tabPanel = new TabPanel { HeaderText = server.GetDescription() };
            var updatePanel = new UpdatePanel();
            var upChilds = updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls;
            var label = new Label { Text = "Hello from UP-" + tabPanel.HeaderText, ID = "lbl" + tabPanel.HeaderText};
            upChilds.Add(label);
            const string command = @"var ctrl = $.find(""{0}""); alert(ctrl.id); return false;";
            var button = new Button {Text = "Button"};
            upChilds.Add(button);

            tabPanel.Controls.Add(updatePanel);


            tbcErrors.Tabs.Add(tabPanel);
            button.OnClientClick = string.Format(command, label.ClientID);
        }
```

so generated html here:
[image]

for a start i just want to create a messagebox with id of control, but even this simple code doesn't work. Question is: why? And how to solve it?

---

Added: ctrl ***is not null***

when command is

```
const string command = @"var ctrl = $.find(""{0}""); alert(((ctrl != null).toString() + ' ') + ctrl.id); return false;";
```

result is `true undefined`

Comment: Well, you have at least one issue: `@"var ctrl = $.find(""{0}""); alert(ctrl.id); return false;";` What do you expect to "0" to be? You need to format that string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: If you say: ctrl is not null ... Please tell us what ctrl actually is.

Comment: I would suspect the ctrl would be an empty array

Comment: @WolleVanillebärLutz, you're right, type if "array of native"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be
`const string command = @"var ctrl = $('#{0}')[0]; ctrl.innerText = 'Updated!'; return false;";`

Why I say this is in jquery to select an element with an id you would use the same convention as a css selector which means you need to prefix the id with a '#' so `$('#elementid')` will select for a DOM element like `<label id="elementid" />` what I would do is

```
    foreach (var pair in FailedMonitorings)
    {
        var server = (ServerEnum)pair.Key;
        var tabPanel = new TabPanel { HeaderText = server.GetDescription() };
        var updatePanel = new UpdatePanel();
        var upChilds = updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls;
        var label = new Label { Text = "Hello from UP-" + tabPanel.HeaderText, ID = "lbl" + tabPanel.HeaderText};
        upChilds.Add(label);
        const string command = @"updateText('{0}')";
        var button = new Button {Text = "Button"};
        upChilds.Add(button);

        tabPanel.Controls.Add(updatePanel);


        tbcErrors.Tabs.Add(tabPanel);
        button.OnClientClick = string.Format(command, label.ClientID);
    }
```

then in html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateText(id){
    var ctrl = $('#' + id);
    ctrl.text('Updated text');
    return false;
}
</script>
```

I prefer that the button call an updateText function as a posed to rendering all the code inline to the client. It makes the code easier to maintain without having to recompile server side. If you need to work with a dom element then you could use `var ctrl = $('#' + id)[0];` this would return the first dom element found for the jquery selection once you have it then you can set the innerText to a value `ctrl.innerText = 'Updated!';`. I didn't do that in my answer because I just wanted to show how it could be done purely from jquery.

The code
`const string command = @"var ctrl = $.find(""{0}""); alert(((ctrl != null).toString() + ' ') + ctrl.id); return false;";`

will not work firstly because your jquery selector `var ctrl = $.find(""{0}"");` will not select the correct control on the client. It would probably render script something like

```
<button onclick="var ctrl = $.find("Ctrl$Label1");alert(((ctrl != null).toString() + ' ') + ctrl.id); return false;" />
```

which means that ctrl would not be null but an empty array as there is no dom element like `Ctrl$Label1` and since arrays don't have a property of id, it would be undefined. what you are after is a '#' in front of the clientId. The second reason this still will return undefined is that even if you do have a valid selector. Is that the JQuery object returned doesn't have a property of id so you will still see undefined. So finally to get both the id and get the correct selector it would look like

`const string command = @"var ctrl = $('#{0}')[0]; alert(ctrl.id); return false;`

or if you need to set the text it would look like

`const string command =@ "var ctrl = $('#{0}')[0]; ctrl.innerText = 'Updated!; return false;`

Comment: `@"var ctrl = $.find('{0}'); alert(ctrl.id); return false;";`

Comment: if copy-paste your code, it do nothing, if just add $(...) result is same as i had before.

Comment: +1 for injecting just function calls instead of whole functions!

Comment: Correct answer is `var ctrl = $('#{0}')[0]` (tnx for google chrome console). And innerText instead of val property. Final command is `"var ctrl = $('#{0}')[0]; ctrl.innerText = 'Updated!'; return false;"` 

so please edit your answer and I'l mark it.

Comment: done. just as a point if val() doesn't work you could use text() instead but i think that's enough for now

Comment: in my case ctrl.val is function, so it doesn't work, but can be called as ctrl.val() that returns an empty string. :D

Comment: It depends on what you set ctrl to and in which context you want to use it. In a purely jQuery context val is used for input use val('something') to set a value and .val() to read a value, but a label is not an input so you use text instead .text('something') to set a value and .text() to read a value (the intial post of val was a mistake on my part). If don't what to use the jquery object you can use the DOM element instead then as you suggested $('#' + id)[0] will bring back the DOM element to work with.